# Message field lost focus after ALT+SHIFT

Tags: skypedeveloper

ArchLinux, KDE.
Skype version 8.51.0.72
$ pacaur -S skypeforlinux-stable-bin

I have two keyboard layouts. I switch them by "ALT+SHIFT" combination.

1. Click to "Type a message here" field
2. Press "ALT-SHIFT"
3. "Type a message here" field LOST focus :(
4. Focus jump to Menubar.

I expect that focus will not be changed when I typing text and press "ALT+SHIFT" key combination.

VEEERY annoying bug.

How can I fix that?

Thank you!